# Is it possible to override Orika's built in converter - XMLGregorianCalendar to java.util.Date?

Tags: java, date, orika, xmlgregoriancalendar

Orika has a set of "BuiltinConverters"

https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/blob/master/core/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/converter/builtin/BuiltinConverters.java

But the one that maps XMLGregorianCalendar to java.util.Date does not work properly for me. I discovered the way to map it with a satisfying result, but I cannot find a way to make Orika use it instead of its own built in converter. I tried registering the converter in MapperDefinition:

```
public class MapperDefinition {

   private final MapperFactory factory;
   private final ConverterFactory converterFactory;

   public MapperDefinition() {

     factory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
     converterFactory = factory.getConverterFactory();

     converterFactory.registerConverter(new CustomConverter<XMLGregorianCalendar, Date>() {
       @Override
       public Date convert(XMLGregorianCalendar source, Type<? extends Date> destinationType) {
         LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(source.getYear(), source.getMonth(), 
             source.getDay(), source.getHour(), source.getMinute(), source.getSecond());
         return Date.from(ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
       }
     }
   }

}
```

But debugging shows that Orika seems to ignore my custom converter and still uses its own built-in converter. I also cannot find any information about overriding it on Orika User Guide:

https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/converters.html

Does anyone know if it's possible to make Orika use my way of mapping those two types?

Comment: I assume what your code does is it registers your converter in that one specific factory, but mapper factory might return distinct factories in some cases. Are you sure your application uses the factory you register into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

The thing is, the built-in converter is a "BidirectionalConverter" and I used "CustomConverter", because I was only interested in changing mapping in one way: XML --> Date. Changing it to bidirectional solved the problem.

Comment: Whether converter bidirectional or not should not matter for one-way conversion, factory still has to use what it was configured with. You have a workaround that works via some side-effect, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to report it as an issue to Orika guys, so they can either fix the problem with their builtin or somehow make it so their builtins don't override custom converters that you register.

As a workaround, I suggest you disable the use of builtins on the builder, and register builtin converters only after you registered all your custom converters and overrides. That should (at least judging by how their `DefaultConverterFactory` currently works) give your custom converters the precedence needed to suppress the builtins.

The code:

```
factory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder()
  .useBuiltinConverters(false)
  .build();
converterFactory = factory.getConverterFactory();

converterFactory.registerConverter(<... Your converter here ...>);

BuiltinConverters.register(converterFactory);
```